# Having trouble getting CSS files to work in CodeSandbox

Tags: codesandbox

I'm having trouble getting CSS to work / be included in the codesandboxes I create. My aim is to simply create a sandbox that includes a few different CSS and JavaScript files, and have these files work with the HTML tags in the index.html file.

I found a sandbox online with working CSS, but the way it was including CSS seemed similar to what I was doing. I decided to slowly change my sandbox into their sandbox to see if I could spot the difference, but after completely changing my sandbox into their sandbox, I was left with one sandbox with working CSS and one with CSS that doesn't work - yet these sandboxes look identical to me.

CSS doesn't work: (except for the inline CSS)
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-rubin-cytfo?file=/index.html

CSS does work:
https://codesandbox.io/s/01-3-ways-to-add-css-forked-9dwq5?file=/index.html

Can someone help me understand why CSS works in one and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. In the "Sandbox Info" section, the "Environment" is different between the two sandboxes. One is "parcel" and one is "create-react-app". create-react-app uses webpack, and bundles files differently than parcel, which is why the CSS works in one and not the other. In the create-react-app version, it doesn't know to bundle the CSS.